# How to append a new node in Hpricot

Tags: ruby, hpricot

I have a DOM and I want to insert a new node using Hpricot. Here my DOM structure:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
    ...

  </body>
</html>
```

What I want is I have to insert a script tag as a last child of `<body>` something like:

```
<body>
  ...
  <script>
    console.log(document.cookie)
  </script>
</body>
```

This is what I have:

```
doc = Hpricot.XML(%{<html>
                     <head>
                      </head>
                      <body>
                        ...
                        ...
                      </body>
                    </html>
                   })

doc.at('body')
```

But now I'm not getting any desired method to move forward and the documentation of hpricot sucks. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: If you're not too heavily invested, [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) is a good alternative to Hpricot.

Comment: @tadman for encouraging me to try nokigiri once again found it using nokogiri at last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achieved but using Nokigiri pasting it incase if someone want to do this

Here the HTML

```
  h1 = Nokogiri::XML.parse %{<html>
      <head>
          <script>
            alert("hello");
          </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <p> THIS IS WAR </p>
      </body>
    </html>}
```

apend your tag (my case script tag) as last child of body

```
h1.search('body').children.after(%{<script> alert ('Hello') </script>})
```

Hope this help to some